# Microsoft access end of records error '2105'

Tags: forms, ms-access, if-statement, record

I have a Microsoft access form that allows users to navigate through records via two buttons "Back" and "Next". The problem is that if a user is on the first record and clicks "Back" a really tacky error message appears. How can I prevent this from happening?

So pretty much, If the record selected is =1 and Back button is pressed then do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Previous record:

```
If CurrentRecord <> 1 Then DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
```

Next record:

```
If CurrentRecord <> Recordset.RecordCount Then DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting your error handler accordingly:

```
Private Sub Back_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
     '...

ExitHandle:
  ' UNINITIALIZE SET OBJECTS
  Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
  If Err.Number = 2105 Then
     DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
  Else
     MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
  End if
  Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```